# If $\mathcal{E}$ is a locally free sheaf and $j:U\to X$ is an open immersion, is $j_*j^* \mathcal{E}$ also locally free?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $j:U\to X$ be an open immersion of schemes (feel free to suppose that they're algebraic varieties or even other conditions) and $\mathcal{E}$ be a locally free sheaf on $X$.

**Is it true that $j_*j^* \mathcal{E}$ is locally free on $X$? If not, is it coherent?**

I know that the direct image of a locally free isn't in general locally free. But perhaps the fact that we're taking the direct image of the restriction of a locally free sheaf plays a role here?

Comment: Not in general - cross site duplicate of [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/201956/pushforward-of-locally-free-sheaves-under-open-immersion).

Comment: @KReiser I don't see why that's a duplicate. In the question that you said we take a locally free sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on $U$ and then push forward it to $X$. In my question we only consider those $\mathcal{F}$ of the form $j^*\mathcal{E}$ for some locally free sheaf $\mathcal{E}$ on $X$.

Comment: Take $X=\operatorname{Spec} A$, $U=\operatorname{Spec} A_f$ for some non-zero divisor $f\in A$ and the locally free sheaf on $X$ to be just $A$. Then you get a non-coherent sheaf.